# Comparing strings with Javascript

Tags: javascript

See the following comparisons:

```
("a" == "a")
true

(/a/ == /a/)
false
```

Why do I get different results with the following expressions?

**EDIT:**

Now I am using just `==` and still getting the same results.

Comment: The second one is not a string match. String match will be `"/a/"=="/a/"` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined`, `null`, `Numbers`, `Strings` literals and `Booleans` are value types in javascript.

So, they will be compared with their *value* unlike `RegExp`(or any other Object for that matter) which is an object, where the comparison takes place on the grounds of *reference.* So `"a" == "a"` will return `true` because the *values* are **same** but `/a/ == /a/` will return `false` because the **references** are different.

Answer (score 6):

The literal `/a/` is not a string, it's a regular expression object. No two objects are `===` to each other.

Comment: Two object instances are always != to each other, even if they are of the same type and have all their respective properties equal.

Comment: @ReginaFlats just try `typeof /a/`, you'll get the answer.

Comment: Object instances are only equal if it is the same instance. You can do `var a = /a/;` and then `a === a` or `a == a` are true.